# Assign the ordered number based on two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame including students' test participation in different years. Here is part of the data frame.

```
ID  level4  level6        exametime
1     0       1       2015-12-19 15:00:00
1     1       0       2015-06-20 09:00:00
1     0       1       2016-06-19 15:00:00
1     0       1       2017-06-17 15:00:00
2     0       1       2015-12-19 15:00:00
2     1       0       2015-06-20 09:00:00
2     0       1       2016-06-19 15:00:00
2     0       1       2017-06-17 15:00:00
2     0       1       2016-12-17 15:00:00
```

There are two students participating in two exams (level4 and level6). The level4 and level6 are binary variables indicating if the student participated in the exam or not. I want to create two variables (order_4 and order_6) indicating the order of each student taking exam based on the order of examtimes. The final result should look like this:

```
ID  level4  level6        exametime          order_4    order_6
1     0       1       2015-12-19 15:00:00       0          1
1     1       0       2015-06-20 09:00:00       1          0
1     0       1       2016-06-19 15:00:00       0          2
1     0       1       2017-06-17 15:00:00       0          3
2     0       1       2015-12-19 15:00:00       0          1
2     1       0       2015-06-20 09:00:00       1          0
2     0       1       2016-06-19 15:00:00       0          2
2     0       1       2017-06-17 15:00:00       0          4
2     0       1       2016-12-17 15:00:00       0          3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `arrange` the data by `exametime` and calculate cumulative sum of values in columns `level4` and `level6` for each `ID`. Cumulative sum is replaced with 0 where the value is 0 in respective level columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(ID, exametime) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('level'), ~replace(cumsum(.), . == 0, 0), .names = 'order_{col}')) %>%
  arrange(row) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)

#     ID level4 level6 exametime           order_level4 order_level6
#  <int>  <int>  <int> <dttm>                     <dbl>        <dbl>
#1     1      0      1 2015-12-19 15:00:00            0            1
#2     1      1      0 2015-06-20 09:00:00            1            0
#3     1      0      1 2016-06-19 15:00:00            0            2
#4     1      0      1 2017-06-17 15:00:00            0            3
#5     2      0      1 2015-12-19 15:00:00            0            1
#6     2      1      0 2015-06-20 09:00:00            1            0
#7     2      0      1 2016-06-19 15:00:00            0            2
#8     2      0      1 2017-06-17 15:00:00            0            4
#9     2      0      1 2016-12-17 15:00:00            0            3
```

I created a temporary column called `row` to maintain the original order of rows.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), level4 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), level6 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), exametime = structure(c(1450537200, 1434790800, 
1466348400, 1497711600, 1450537200, 1434790800, 1466348400, 1497711600, 
1481986800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```